# Obtener solamente el primer registro segun un campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, heidisql

Les comento, tengo una query donde necesito que por cada expediente, solamente me muestre la primer fila, en caso que tenga mas. En este caso, estoy probando con un expediente_j_id que tiene 5 registros pero solo necesito que me muestre el primero. La verdad ya se me terminaron las ideas, probe con distinct o consultas anidadas y nada.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sej.id, sej.fecha_cambio, sej.estado_proceso_j_id, epj.abrev, sej.expediente_j_id, ej.ultimo_seguimiento_estado_expediente_j_id, sej.usuario, ej.tipo_doc_empresa_id, tde.descripcion, ej.doc_empresa, ej.razon_social, ej.tipo_transporte_id, tp.descripcion, aej.acta_cabecera_id, nro_acta, fecha_acta FROM seguimiento_estado_expediente_j sej
INNER JOIN expediente_j ej ON sej.expediente_j_id = ej.id
INNER JOIN acta_expediente_j aej ON sej.expediente_j_id = aej.acta_cabecera_id
INNER JOIN acta_cabecera ac ON aej.acta_cabecera_id = ac.id
INNER JOIN estado_proceso_j epj ON sej.estado_proceso_j_id = epj.id
INNER JOIN tipo_transporte tp ON ej.tipo_transporte_id = tp.id
INNER JOIN tipo_doc_empresa tde ON ej.tipo_doc_empresa_id = tde.id
LEFT JOIN seguimiento_estado_expediente_j s2 ON (sej.expediente_j_id=s2.expediente_j_id AND sej.id>s2.id)
WHERE
sej.estado_proceso_j_id=1 AND s2.estado_proceso_j_id=1 AND sej.fecha_cambio BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-09-01 23:59:59' AND sej.expediente_j_id = '95154'
ORDER BY 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mmm... te refieres a ¿`LIMIT 1`?

Comment: No, porque ahí filtre la query. Pero la idea es buscar todos los expedientes y que solamente aparezca uno por expediente_id. Si hago un LIMIT 1 apareceria solamente un registro cuando busque todos los expedientes...

Comment: Y no es eso lo que quieres? que solo aparezca un registro? Dices que la consulta te devuelve varios y que solo quieres uno... aplicale el limit 1 y solucionado, no? O hay algo mal redactado en la pregunta y estamos entendiendo lo que no es?

Comment: @Pipe La ha redactado bien, pero ambos no hemos caido en la cuenta de la primera frase: `necesito que por cada expediente, solamente me muestre la primer fila,` :-)  Estaba pensando en GROUP BY o NUM_ROWS, pero no lo tengo claro, así que espero que aparezcan mejores expertos en MySQL y ver su respuesta, je

Comment: @masterguru pues no hay misterio, no te equivocas, se puede resolver con un `GROUP BY` y/o con un `MAX()` o un `MIN()` según quiera el primero o el último de un orden dado. OP dice que quiere el *primero*, pero no define a qué llama él *primero*. ¿Qué es el *primero*, en qué columna y según qué orden? Hay primeros últimos y últimos primeros.

Comment: @A.Cedano Eso del MAX() o MIN() era lo que me faltaba para tenerlo claro, je, muchas gracias (no voy a postear respuesta igualmente, lo mio no es precisamente el mysql, solo para cosas muy simples, sírvete hacerlo tu si te apetece)

Comment: Gracias los 3, a partir de group by y la idea del max min. Lo resolvi con un 
´´´
GROUP by sej.expediente_j_id
ORDER BY 1 ASC,2

´´´

Comment: @AgustinMaldonado pues si no te importa agrega tu mismo la respuesta completa y así la comunidad lo sabrá (y en 48 horas podrás aceptarla para darle más visibildad), gracias!

Comment: Dale, ahí lo subo

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los comentarios así quedo la solucion. Gracias a los que comentaron!

```
SELECT sej.id, sej.fecha_cambio, sej.estado_proceso_j_id, epj.abrev, sej.expediente_j_id, sej.usuario, ej.tipo_doc_empresa_id, tde.descripcion, ej.doc_empresa, ej.razon_social, ej.tipo_transporte_id, tp.descripcion, aej.acta_cabecera_id, nro_acta, fecha_acta FROM seguimiento_estado_expediente_j sej
INNER JOIN expediente_j ej ON sej.expediente_j_id = ej.id
INNER JOIN acta_expediente_j aej ON sej.expediente_j_id = aej.acta_cabecera_id
INNER JOIN acta_cabecera ac ON aej.acta_cabecera_id = ac.id
INNER JOIN estado_proceso_j epj ON sej.estado_proceso_j_id = epj.id
INNER JOIN tipo_transporte tp ON ej.tipo_transporte_id = tp.id
INNER JOIN tipo_doc_empresa tde ON ej.tipo_doc_empresa_id = tde.id
WHERE
sej.estado_proceso_j_id=1 AND sej.fecha_cambio BETWEEN '2022-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-19 23:59:59' 
GROUP by sej.expediente_j_id
ORDER BY 1 ASC,2
```